# Could not open port for activeMQ broker on CentOS

Tags: centos, port

Here is my problem:

We have a virtual machine on VMware ESXi with CentOS 6.3 system (devserver). We use port forwarding to access ports on the virtual machine.

We deploy our application in tomcat on the devserver (Tomcat7,JDK7)

Iptables is disabled.

After deployment, ActiveMQ start to listen on 60001 port. The application on 8080 works fine:

1. we can access it from another VM in ESXi subnet, using port 8080
2. and from internet we can access it on port 8585, which is forwarded to port 8080 on the devserver
3. our client tries to listen on 60001 for ActiveMQ broker, but that port is closed!

When I check port 60001 with nmap on localhost and on 127.0.0.1, it is open:

```
nmap -v -sV localhost -p 60001
60001/tcp open  activemq Apache ActiveMQ
```

And when I try to access it using the external IP, it is closed:

```
nmap -v -sV 192.168.11.105 -p 60001
60001/tcp closed unknown

netstat -an | grep 60001
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:60001      :::*                        LISTEN

service iptables status
Firewall is not running.
```

Where do I start searching for the solution?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know ActiveMQ, but from netstat you can see, that it listens only on localhost: "127.0.0.1:60001". Try to check documentation about listening IP .There is similar question on  [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318439/how-can-one-use-activemq-not-locally)

Comment: So, is it application problem, and not system configuration?

Comment: Yes, application says which IP and port need. As I wrote, I don't know Active MQ - in [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html) is something about XML config file with `transportConnector` options

Comment: Yes, it was ActiveMQ Broker configuration:
localhost:60001 -> 0.0.0.0:60001